# How to make canvas bigger in the python turtle module

Tags: python, size, turtle-graphics

I made a turtle drawing program in python, but my canvas in which the turtle draws is not big enough. I am trying to make this canvas bigger so that I can fit more on the page and make the stuff bigger. I am programming this in trinket.io.

Answer (score 6):

> I am programming this in trinket.io.

That is your problem -- Unfortunately, this is not possible in trinket.io.

Trinket.io does not support all the `turtle` methods.  You can read which ones are supported [here](https://trinket.io/#turtle); I assume the rest are unsupported.

This will work on your local python interpreter:

```
import turtle

print(turtle.Screen().screensize()) # returns (400,300) for me
```

But this will fail in Trinket.io, with a message like:

```
> AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'screensize' on line 3 in main.py
```

The documentation implies that `turtle.setup()` is supported, however, it seems not to be, because this will work on your local python interpreter and fail in trinket.io.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(500,500)
```

The only thing I have been able to do in trinket.io is to be able to return (not set) the dimensions, via:

```
print(turtle.window_height())
print(turtle.window_width())
```

Comment: I was able to set the screen size following the example [here](https://trinket.io/embed/python/8eb5179d7f#.X2AAHoZlDs0) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893204/199217

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use:

```py
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
# this assures that the size of the screen will always be 400x400 ...
screen.setup(500, 500)
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.goto(200,200)
tina.goto(-200,-200)
tina.goto(-200,200)
tina.goto(200,-200)
```

Here is my [trinket :-)](https://trinket.io/python/44085630f2)

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle
turtle.screensize(canvwidth=None, canvheight=None, bg=None)
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape('turtle')
your_name = input("What is your name")

tina.penup()
tina.forward(20)
tina.write("Why, hello there, " + your_name + "!", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
tina.backward(20)
tina.color("green")
tina.left(90)
tina.forward(100)
tina.right(90)
tina.goto(-65, 50)
tina.pendown()
tina.pencolor("red")
tina.forward(50)
tina.right(50)
tina.forward(50)
tina.right(100)
tina.forward(55)
tina.left(50)
tina.forward(55)
tina.penup()
tina.forward(30)
tina.pendown()
tina.dot(10)
tina.penup()
tina.goto(-100, 100)
color = input("What color is the question mark")
try:
  if color == ("red"):
    tina.write("Your are correct " + your_name + "!", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("green" or "Green"):
    tina.left(90)
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    tina.forward(100)
  elif color == ("black" or "Black"):
    tina.write("Sorry, Its is actually Red", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("purple" or "Purple"):
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("blue" or "Blue"):
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
    tina.backward(20)
except:
  tina.backward(20)
  tina.write("Sorry, but that isn't a color", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))
  tina.backward(20)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or is this your current code? If the latter, you should include this in your question, not in an answer post.