# Finding size of turtle screen in replit

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to find the size of the turtle screen in replit so that I can know where the turtle has went out of bounds.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle as t
from random import randint as r
import sys

window = t.Screen()
pet = t.Turtle()

def rand_color():
  red = r(0, 255)
  green = r(0, 255)
  blue = r(0, 255)
  pet.color(red, green, blue)

def random_turtle(num_moves):
  global count
  while count < num_moves:
    rand_color()
    pet.forward(r(10, 100))
    check()
    pet.right(r(0, 360))
    check()
    count += 1 

def check():
  global count
  x = t.xcor()
  y = t.ycor()
  if x > 350 or x < -350:
    t.right(180)
    if count > 100:
      sys.stop()
    else:
      random_turtle(100 - count)
  elif y > 330 or y < -320:
    t.right(180)
    if count > 100:
      sys.stop()
    else:
      random_turtle(100 - count)
  else:
    random_turtle(100 - count)
```

If there is an easier method than finding the size of the turtle screen and dividing the x by 2, please let me know in the comments!

Comment: Hi! What exactly is your question? Please include your code and point out your issue and where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the size of my python turtle window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528067/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-my-python-turtle-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask turtle itself, even in Repl.it:

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
print(screen.window_width(), screen.window_height())
```

Repl console output:

```
Starting X
.....400 450
>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know!