# I tried to configure the window height and width with python turtle but this error keeps popping up

Tags: python, python-turtle

I was trying to configure the window with

```
window_height(300)
window_height(300)
```

And this is the error I received.
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEMjh.png)

I tried to change the line, nothing.
Checked the problems tab
...
nothing

Any fixes for this problem?

Comment: don't screenshot the error. Paste it as text

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.window_height) for `window_height`: it's a getter, not a setter, so there are no parameters you can pass. Try [`screen.setup(width, height)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530216/6243352).

Comment: Thanks, I used turtle.screensize(300, 300) because screen.setup() doesn't exist, thanks for solving the problem